# DataGrid on UserControl doesn't display binded ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, user-controls

I have a MainWindow with some buttons that loads a collection:

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.MainWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mainWindowViewModel="clr-namespace:GUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Helpers"
        xmlns:configuration="clr-namespace:GUI.Configuration"
        xmlns:results="clr-namespace:GUI.Results"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="{Binding Path=Model.Title}"
        Width="Auto"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type results:ResultViewModel}">
             <results:ResultView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <!--DataContext-->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <mainWindowViewModel:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <!--DataContext-->

    <!--Main Grid-->
    <Grid Name="MainGrid"
          Margin="5"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Tabs-->
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <!--Result View-->
            <TabItem Header="{Binding Model.TabImportHeader}">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding ResultViewModel}"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <!--Tabs-->

        <!--Buttons-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="10"
                    Height="25"
                    Width="150"
                    Content="Load"
                    Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" />
            <Button Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Margin="10"
                    Height="25"
                    Width="150"
                    Content="Reload"
                    Command="{Binding ReloadCommand}" />
        </Grid>
        <!--Buttons-->

    </Grid>
    <!--Main Grid-->
</Window>
```

Then I have a UserControl which should display the loaded collection, but shows nothing.

```
<UserControl x:Class="GUI.Results.ResultView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI.Results"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ResultViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="87*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="415*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="501*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Collections}"
                              ColumnWidth="*"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                        Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Filename"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Filename}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score 1"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Score1, StringFormat=F4, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score 2"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Score2, StringFormat=F4, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score 3"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Score3, StringFormat=F4, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score 4"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Score4, StringFormat=F4, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SaMP"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.SaMP}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Spig"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Spig}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ppig"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Ppig, StringFormat=00.0##\\%}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pigment3"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Pigment3}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pigment4"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Pigment4}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ZQ1"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.ZQ1}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ZQ2"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.ZQ2}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ZQ3"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.ZQ3}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ZQ4"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.ZQ4}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.Message}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Distance"
                                                Binding="{Binding ResultInfo.PowDistance, StringFormat=F2, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
                                                Width="Auto" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here how I put the data inside the collection (values are there if I debug):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MainWindowViewModel.ResultViewModel.Model.Collections.Add(Collection));
```

`Collections` is type of ObservableCollection<>;

Seems that I'm missing something in the binding but I'm quite new to WPF and MVVM and I don't find it.
I have read about DependencyProperty but I would like to have a ViewModel for my userControl as it will get eventually more complex.

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged? Where are you filling your collection? (i mean it's a method or at initialization?)

Comment: Yes, the ResultModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and I raise the event on the set, plus, the collection is type of ObservableCollection.
The collection is filled with a method that raise from a Command on the MainWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances of `ResultViewModel`, one in the `MainWindowViewModel.ResultViewModel` property, the other directly assigned to the UserControl's DataContext:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ResultViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Remove the above from the UserControl's XAML.

In general, a UserControl should never have its "own" view model, and you should never explicitly set its DataContext property in its XAML or code behind. Doing so overrides the value of the inherited DataContext, which contains the correct ResultViewModel instance.

Comment: Hi, okey, its working if I delete the assignment of the UserControl's DataContext.
Also is working if I do the following:
`<results:ResultView DataContext="{Binding ResultViewModel}"/>` instead of
`<ContentControl Content="{Binding ResultViewModel}" />`

Thanks for your answer!